# Unable to run Python script exported from ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to execute a code exported from ModelBuilder which basically extracts buildings with type a and m from a feature class in one database and append it to another feature class in a different database.

I am able to manually run the model as a python script in pyscript but only once.

After that I run it, but there are no change in the count of records.

`RILGDB.Building` is the  input feature class that keeps getting updated everyday in the database.

`GIS_USER_Building` is the output feature class where I need to append the updated buildings

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
# Local variables:
RILGDB_Building__2_ = "Database Connections\\LB.sde\\RILGDB.Buildings\\RILGDB.Building"
buildingmake = "C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake"
GIS_USER_BUILDING_ = buildingmake
GIS_USER_BUILDING = "Database Connections\\SAP HANA GIS_USER.sde\\GIS_USER.BUILDING"

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(RILGDB_Building__2_, buildingmake, "BUILDING_RJID IN (SELECT BUILDING_RJID FROM APP_MDM.BUILDING WHERE  TRANSACTION_TYPE in('A','M') AND TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')=TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MM-YY'))", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;RILUNIQUEID RILUNIQUEID VISIBLE NONE;RILFEATURECODE RILFEATURECODE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGNO BLDGNO VISIBLE NONE;BLDGNAME BLDGNAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGTYPE BLDGTYPE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSUBTYPE BLDGSUBTYPE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCLASS BLDGCLASS VISIBLE NONE;BLDGROAD BLDGROAD VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSUBROAD BLDGSUBROAD VISIBLE NONE;SUBLOCALITY SUBLOCALITY VISIBLE NONE;STATENAME STATENAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSIZE BLDGSIZE VISIBLE NONE;TAG TAG VISIBLE NONE;PINCODE PINCODE VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFFLATS NUMBEROFFLATS VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFSHOPS NUMBEROFSHOPS VISIBLE NONE;BLDG_TYPE BLDG_TYPE VISIBLE NONE;CABLEOPERATORNAME CABLEOPERATORNAME VISIBLE NONE;AREA_1 AREA_1 VISIBLE NONE;LBU2 LBU2 VISIBLE NONE;SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCONDITION BLDGCONDITION VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCONSTRUCTION BLDGCONSTRUCTION VISIBLE NONE;AFFLUENCEINDICATOR AFFLUENCEINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;ROOFTOPANTENNA ROOFTOPANTENNA VISIBLE NONE;REMARKS REMARKS VISIBLE NONE;VINTAGE VINTAGE VISIBLE NONE;BOI BOI VISIBLE NONE;NETWORKREF NETWORKREF VISIBLE NONE;NOOFCOMMERCIAL NOOFCOMMERCIAL VISIBLE NONE;BUILDING_RJID BUILDING_RJID VISIBLE NONE;UPDATESOURCE UPDATESOURCE VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;PLOTSURVEYNO PLOTSURVEYNO VISIBLE NONE;TPY_ID TPY_ID VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITYNAME LOCALITYNAME VISIBLE NONE;SUBSUBLOCALITY SUBSUBLOCALITY VISIBLE NONE;CITYCODE CITYCODE VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITYCODE LOCALITYCODE VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITY_RJID LOCALITY_RJID VISIBLE NONE;DATASOURCE DATASOURCE VISIBLE NONE;CREATED_USER CREATED_USER VISIBLE NONE;CREATED_DATE CREATED_DATE VISIBLE NONE;LAST_EDITED_USER LAST_EDITED_USER VISIBLE NONE;LAST_EDITED_DATE LAST_EDITED_DATE VISIBLE NONE;LTERFS LTERFS VISIBLE NONE;FTTXRFS FTTXRFS VISIBLE NONE;BLCMSTATUS BLCMSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;TALUKCODE TALUKCODE VISIBLE NONE;TALUKNAME TALUKNAME VISIBLE NONE;DISTRICTCODE DISTRICTCODE VISIBLE NONE;DISTRICTNAME DISTRICTNAME VISIBLE NONE;BOICATEGORY BOICATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;LTE_COVERAGE LTE_COVERAGE VISIBLE NONE;NEIGHBOURHOODCODE NEIGHBOURHOODCODE VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTERNAME JIOCENTERNAME VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFFLOORS NUMBEROFFLOORS VISIBLE NONE;VILLAGENAME VILLAGENAME VISIBLE NONE;VILLAGE_RJID VILLAGE_RJID VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTERCODE JIOCENTERCODE VISIBLE NONE;BLDG_CATEGORY BLDG_CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;GLOBALID_1 GLOBALID_1 VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTER_RJID JIOCENTER_RJID VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTER_SAP_ID JIOCENTER_SAP_ID VISIBLE NONE;INCOME_LEVEL INCOME_LEVEL VISIBLE NONE;CITYNAME CITYNAME VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE.AREA SHAPE.AREA VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE.LEN SHAPE.LEN VISIBLE NONE")

# Process: Append
arcpy.Append_management("C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake", GIS_USER_BUILDING, "NO_TEST", "RILUNIQUEID \"RILUNIQUEID\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,RILUNIQUEID,-1,-1;RILFEATURECODE \"RILFEATURECODE\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,RILFEATURECODE,-1,-1;BLDGNO \"BLDGNO\" true true false 20 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGNO,-1,-1;BLDGNAME \"BLDGNAME\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGNAME,-1,-1;BLDGTYPE \"BLDGTYPE\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGTYPE,-1,-1;BLDGSUBTYPE \"BLDGSUBTYPE\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSUBTYPE,-1,-1;BLDGCLASS \"BLDGCLASS\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCLASS,-1,-1;BLDGROAD \"BLDGROAD\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGROAD,-1,-1;BLDGSUBROAD \"BLDGSUBROAD\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSUBROAD,-1,-1;SUBLOCALITY \"SUBLOCALITY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SUBLOCALITY,-1,-1;CITYNAME \"CITYNAME\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CITYNAME,-1,-1;STATENAME \"STATENAME\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,STATENAME,-1,-1;BLDGSIZE \"BLDGSIZE\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSIZE,-1,-1;TAG \"TAG\" true true false 5 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TAG,-1,-1;PINCODE \"PINCODE\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,PINCODE,-1,-1;NUMBEROFFLATS \"NUMBEROFFLATS\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFFLATS,-1,-1;NUMBEROFSHOPS \"NUMBEROFSHOPS\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFSHOPS,-1,-1;BLDG_TYPE \"BLDG_TYPE\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDG_TYPE,-1,-1;CABLEOPERATORNAME \"CABLEOPERATORNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CABLEOPERATORNAME,-1,-1;AREA_1 \"AREA_1\" true true false 8 Double 8 38 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,AREA_1,-1,-1;LBU2 \"LBU2\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LBU2,-1,-1;SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME \"SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME\" true true false 250 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME,-1,-1;BLDGCONDITION \"BLDGCONDITION\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCONDITION,-1,-1;BLDGCONSTRUCTION \"BLDGCONSTRUCTION\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCONSTRUCTION,-1,-1;AFFLUENCEINDICATOR \"AFFLUENCEINDICATOR\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,AFFLUENCEINDICATOR,-1,-1;ROOFTOPANTENNA \"ROOFTOPANTENNA\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,ROOFTOPANTENNA,-1,-1;REMARKS \"REMARKS\" true true false 250 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,REMARKS,-1,-1;VINTAGE \"VINTAGE\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VINTAGE,-1,-1;BOI \"BOI\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BOI,-1,-1;NETWORKREF \"NETWORKREF\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NETWORKREF,-1,-1;NOOFCOMMERCIAL \"NOOFCOMMERCIAL\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NOOFCOMMERCIAL,-1,-1;BUILDING_RJID \"BUILDING_RJID\" true true false 13 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BUILDING_RJID,-1,-1;UPDATESOURCE \"UPDATESOURCE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,UPDATESOURCE,-1,-1;PLOTSURVEYNO \"PLOTSURVEYNO\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,PLOTSURVEYNO,-1,-1;TPY_ID \"TPY_ID\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TPY_ID,-1,-1;LOCALITYNAME \"LOCALITYNAME\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITYNAME,-1,-1;SUBSUBLOCALITY \"SUBSUBLOCALITY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SUBSUBLOCALITY,-1,-1;CITYCODE \"CITYCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CITYCODE,-1,-1;LOCALITYCODE \"LOCALITYCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITYCODE,-1,-1;LOCALITY_RJID \"LOCALITY_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITY_RJID,-1,-1;DATASOURCE \"DATASOURCE\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DATASOURCE,-1,-1;CREATED_USER \"CREATED_USER\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CREATED_USER,-1,-1;CREATED_DATE \"CREATED_DATE\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CREATED_DATE,-1,-1;LAST_EDITED_USER \"LAST_EDITED_USER\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LAST_EDITED_USER,-1,-1;LAST_EDITED_DATE \"LAST_EDITED_DATE\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LAST_EDITED_DATE,-1,-1;LTERFS \"LTERFS\" true true false 3 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LTERFS,-1,-1;FTTXRFS \"FTTXRFS\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,FTTXRFS,-1,-1;BLCMSTATUS \"BLCMSTATUS\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLCMSTATUS,-1,-1;TALUKCODE \"TALUKCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TALUKCODE,-1,-1;TALUKNAME \"TALUKNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TALUKNAME,-1,-1;DISTRICTCODE \"DISTRICTCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DISTRICTCODE,-1,-1;DISTRICTNAME \"DISTRICTNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DISTRICTNAME,-1,-1;BOICATEGORY \"BOICATEGORY\" true true false 5 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BOICATEGORY,-1,-1;LTE_COVERAGE \"LTE_COVERAGE\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LTE_COVERAGE,-1,-1;NEIGHBOURHOODCODE \"NEIGHBOURHOODCODE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NEIGHBOURHOODCODE,-1,-1;JIOCENTERNAME \"JIOCENTERNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTERNAME,-1,-1;NUMBEROFFLOORS \"NUMBEROFFLOORS\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFFLOORS,-1,-1;VILLAGENAME \"VILLAGENAME\" true true false 60 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VILLAGENAME,-1,-1;VILLAGE_RJID \"VILLAGE_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VILLAGE_RJID,-1,-1;JIOCENTERCODE \"JIOCENTERCODE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTERCODE,-1,-1;BLDG_CATEGORY \"BLDG_CATEGORY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDG_CATEGORY,-1,-1;GLOBALID_1 \"GLOBALID_1\" true false false 38 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,GLOBALID_1,-1,-1;JIOCENTER_RJID \"JIOCENTER_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTER_RJID,-1,-1;JIOCENTER_SAP_ID \"JIOCENTER_SAP_ID\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTER_SAP_ID,-1,-1;INCOME_LEVEL \"INCOME_LEVEL\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,INCOME_LEVEL,-1,-1", "")
```

---

I tried it, somehow it is not working.

However I tried modifying the ode by adding rilgdb.building and gis_user.building as input and output parameters as shown below

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy

# Script arguments
RILGDB_Building__2_ = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
if RILGDB_Building__2_ == '#' or not RILGDB_Building__2_:
RILGDB_Building__2_ = "Database Connections\\LB.sde\\RILGDB.Buildings\\RILGDB.Building" # provide a default value if unspecified

GIS_USER_BUILDING_ = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
if GIS_USER_BUILDING_ == '#' or not GIS_USER_BUILDING_:
GIS_USER_BUILDING_ = "Database Connections\\SAP HANA   GIS_USER.sde\\GIS_USER.BUILDING" # provide a default value if unspecified

# Local variables:
buildingmake =    "C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake"
GIS_USER_BUILDING = "Database Connections\\SAP HANA   GIS_USER.sde\\GIS_USER.BUILDING"

# Process: Make Feature Layer
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(RILGDB_Building__2_, buildingmake,   "BUILDING_RJID IN (SELECT BUILDING_RJID FROM APP_MDM.BUILDING     WHERE  TRANSACTION_TYPE in ('A','M') AND TO_DATE(TRANSACTION_DATE,'DD-MM-YY')=TO_DATE(SYSDATE-1,'DD-MM-YY'))", "", "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;RILUNIQUEID RILUNIQUEID VISIBLE NONE;RILFEATURECODE RILFEATURECODE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGNO BLDGNO VISIBLE NONE;BLDGNAME BLDGNAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGTYPE BLDGTYPE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSUBTYPE BLDGSUBTYPE VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCLASS BLDGCLASS VISIBLE NONE;BLDGROAD BLDGROAD VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSUBROAD BLDGSUBROAD VISIBLE NONE;SUBLOCALITY SUBLOCALITY VISIBLE NONE;STATENAME STATENAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGSIZE BLDGSIZE VISIBLE NONE;TAG TAG VISIBLE NONE;PINCODE PINCODE VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFFLATS NUMBEROFFLATS VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFSHOPS NUMBEROFSHOPS VISIBLE NONE;BLDG_TYPE BLDG_TYPE VISIBLE NONE;CABLEOPERATORNAME CABLEOPERATORNAME VISIBLE NONE;AREA_1 AREA_1 VISIBLE NONE;LBU2 LBU2 VISIBLE NONE;SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCONDITION BLDGCONDITION VISIBLE NONE;BLDGCONSTRUCTION BLDGCONSTRUCTION VISIBLE NONE;AFFLUENCEINDICATOR AFFLUENCEINDICATOR VISIBLE NONE;ROOFTOPANTENNA ROOFTOPANTENNA VISIBLE NONE;REMARKS REMARKS VISIBLE NONE;VINTAGE VINTAGE VISIBLE NONE;BOI BOI VISIBLE NONE;NETWORKREF NETWORKREF VISIBLE NONE;NOOFCOMMERCIAL NOOFCOMMERCIAL VISIBLE NONE;BUILDING_RJID BUILDING_RJID VISIBLE NONE;UPDATESOURCE UPDATESOURCE VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE SHAPE VISIBLE NONE;PLOTSURVEYNO PLOTSURVEYNO VISIBLE NONE;TPY_ID TPY_ID VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITYNAME LOCALITYNAME VISIBLE NONE;SUBSUBLOCALITY SUBSUBLOCALITY VISIBLE NONE;CITYCODE CITYCODE VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITYCODE LOCALITYCODE VISIBLE NONE;LOCALITY_RJID LOCALITY_RJID VISIBLE NONE;DATASOURCE DATASOURCE VISIBLE NONE;CREATED_USER CREATED_USER VISIBLE NONE;CREATED_DATE CREATED_DATE VISIBLE NONE;LAST_EDITED_USER LAST_EDITED_USER VISIBLE NONE;LAST_EDITED_DATE LAST_EDITED_DATE VISIBLE NONE;LTERFS LTERFS VISIBLE NONE;FTTXRFS FTTXRFS VISIBLE NONE;BLCMSTATUS BLCMSTATUS VISIBLE NONE;TALUKCODE TALUKCODE VISIBLE NONE;TALUKNAME TALUKNAME VISIBLE NONE;DISTRICTCODE DISTRICTCODE VISIBLE NONE;DISTRICTNAME DISTRICTNAME VISIBLE NONE;BOICATEGORY BOICATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;LTE_COVERAGE LTE_COVERAGE VISIBLE NONE;NEIGHBOURHOODCODE NEIGHBOURHOODCODE VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTERNAME JIOCENTERNAME VISIBLE NONE;NUMBEROFFLOORS NUMBEROFFLOORS VISIBLE NONE;VILLAGENAME VILLAGENAME VISIBLE NONE;VILLAGE_RJID VILLAGE_RJID VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTERCODE JIOCENTERCODE VISIBLE NONE;BLDG_CATEGORY BLDG_CATEGORY VISIBLE NONE;GLOBALID_1 GLOBALID_1 VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTER_RJID JIOCENTER_RJID VISIBLE NONE;JIOCENTER_SAP_ID JIOCENTER_SAP_ID VISIBLE NONE;INCOME_LEVEL INCOME_LEVEL VISIBLE NONE;CITYNAME CITYNAME VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE.AREA SHAPE.AREA VISIBLE NONE;SHAPE.LEN SHAPE.LEN VISIBLE NONE")

 # Process: Append
   arcpy.Append_management("C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake", GIS_USER_BUILDING, "NO_TEST", "RILUNIQUEID \"RILUNIQUEID\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,RILUNIQUEID,-1,-1;RILFEATURECODE \"RILFEATURECODE\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,RILFEATURECODE,-1,-1;BLDGNO \"BLDGNO\" true true false 20 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGNO,-1,-1;BLDGNAME \"BLDGNAME\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGNAME,-1,-1;BLDGTYPE \"BLDGTYPE\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGTYPE,-1,-1;BLDGSUBTYPE \"BLDGSUBTYPE\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSUBTYPE,-1,-1;BLDGCLASS \"BLDGCLASS\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCLASS,-1,-1;BLDGROAD \"BLDGROAD\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGROAD,-1,-1;BLDGSUBROAD \"BLDGSUBROAD\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSUBROAD,-1,-1;SUBLOCALITY \"SUBLOCALITY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SUBLOCALITY,-1,-1;CITYNAME \"CITYNAME\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CITYNAME,-1,-1;STATENAME \"STATENAME\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,STATENAME,-1,-1;BLDGSIZE \"BLDGSIZE\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGSIZE,-1,-1;TAG \"TAG\" true true false 5 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TAG,-1,-1;PINCODE \"PINCODE\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,PINCODE,-1,-1;NUMBEROFFLATS \"NUMBEROFFLATS\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFFLATS,-1,-1;NUMBEROFSHOPS \"NUMBEROFSHOPS\" true true false 4 Long 0 10 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFSHOPS,-1,-1;BLDG_TYPE \"BLDG_TYPE\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDG_TYPE,-1,-1;CABLEOPERATORNAME \"CABLEOPERATORNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CABLEOPERATORNAME,-1,-1;AREA_1 \"AREA_1\" true true false 8 Double 8 38 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,AREA_1,-1,-1;LBU2 \"LBU2\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LBU2,-1,-1;SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME \"SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME\" true true false 250 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SOCIETYCOMPLEXNAME,-1,-1;BLDGCONDITION \"BLDGCONDITION\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCONDITION,-1,-1;BLDGCONSTRUCTION \"BLDGCONSTRUCTION\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDGCONSTRUCTION,-1,-1;AFFLUENCEINDICATOR \"AFFLUENCEINDICATOR\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,AFFLUENCEINDICATOR,-1,-1;ROOFTOPANTENNA \"ROOFTOPANTENNA\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,ROOFTOPANTENNA,-1,-1;REMARKS \"REMARKS\" true true false 250 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,REMARKS,-1,-1;VINTAGE \"VINTAGE\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VINTAGE,-1,-1;BOI \"BOI\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BOI,-1,-1;NETWORKREF \"NETWORKREF\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NETWORKREF,-1,-1;NOOFCOMMERCIAL \"NOOFCOMMERCIAL\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NOOFCOMMERCIAL,-1,-1;BUILDING_RJID \"BUILDING_RJID\" true true false 13 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BUILDING_RJID,-1,-1;UPDATESOURCE \"UPDATESOURCE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,UPDATESOURCE,-1,-1;PLOTSURVEYNO \"PLOTSURVEYNO\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,PLOTSURVEYNO,-1,-1;TPY_ID \"TPY_ID\" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TPY_ID,-1,-1;LOCALITYNAME \"LOCALITYNAME\" true true false 70 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITYNAME,-1,-1;SUBSUBLOCALITY \"SUBSUBLOCALITY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,SUBSUBLOCALITY,-1,-1;CITYCODE \"CITYCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CITYCODE,-1,-1;LOCALITYCODE \"LOCALITYCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITYCODE,-1,-1;LOCALITY_RJID \"LOCALITY_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LOCALITY_RJID,-1,-1;DATASOURCE \"DATASOURCE\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DATASOURCE,-1,-1;CREATED_USER \"CREATED_USER\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CREATED_USER,-1,-1;CREATED_DATE \"CREATED_DATE\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,CREATED_DATE,-1,-1;LAST_EDITED_USER \"LAST_EDITED_USER\" true true false 255 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LAST_EDITED_USER,-1,-1;LAST_EDITED_DATE \"LAST_EDITED_DATE\" true true false 8 Date 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LAST_EDITED_DATE,-1,-1;LTERFS \"LTERFS\" true true false 3 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LTERFS,-1,-1;FTTXRFS \"FTTXRFS\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,FTTXRFS,-1,-1;BLCMSTATUS \"BLCMSTATUS\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLCMSTATUS,-1,-1;TALUKCODE \"TALUKCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TALUKCODE,-1,-1;TALUKNAME \"TALUKNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,TALUKNAME,-1,-1;DISTRICTCODE \"DISTRICTCODE\" true true false 4 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DISTRICTCODE,-1,-1;DISTRICTNAME \"DISTRICTNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,DISTRICTNAME,-1,-1;BOICATEGORY \"BOICATEGORY\" true true false 5 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BOICATEGORY,-1,-1;LTE_COVERAGE \"LTE_COVERAGE\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,LTE_COVERAGE,-1,-1;NEIGHBOURHOODCODE \"NEIGHBOURHOODCODE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NEIGHBOURHOODCODE,-1,-1;JIOCENTERNAME \"JIOCENTERNAME\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTERNAME,-1,-1;NUMBEROFFLOORS \"NUMBEROFFLOORS\" true true false 2 Short 0 5 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,NUMBEROFFLOORS,-1,-1;VILLAGENAME \"VILLAGENAME\" true true false 60 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VILLAGENAME,-1,-1;VILLAGE_RJID \"VILLAGE_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,VILLAGE_RJID,-1,-1;JIOCENTERCODE \"JIOCENTERCODE\" true true false 10 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTERCODE,-1,-1;BLDG_CATEGORY \"BLDG_CATEGORY\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,BLDG_CATEGORY,-1,-1;GLOBALID_1 \"GLOBALID_1\" true false false 38 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,GLOBALID_1,-1,-1;JIOCENTER_RJID \"JIOCENTER_RJID\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTER_RJID,-1,-1;JIOCENTER_SAP_ID \"JIOCENTER_SAP_ID\" true true false 30 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,JIOCENTER_SAP_ID,-1,-1;INCOME_LEVEL \"INCOME_LEVEL\" true true false 50 Text 0 0 ,First,#,C:\\Users\\Trilok.Chouhan\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\Buildings.gdb\\buildingmake,INCOME_LEVEL,-1,-1", "")
```

It seems to be working everytime I run it as the counts are increasing, however I am not sure whether it is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

Only run once:

You might want to add this to your script.

```
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
```